# Hype-driven Definition

Tags: meaning

What does "hype-driven" means in this paragraph?

> There have been a few examples of Internet criticism making an impact
>   on American film culture. It’s aided the rise of South Korean cinema
>   and mumblecore. In the case of Korean cinema, Filmbrain’s blog, among
>   others, hosted interesting debates on the films of Park Chan-wook, Kim
>   Ki-duk, and Hong Sang-soo. Bloggers like Tom Vick seemed to respond to
>   the snobbery implicit in Tony Rayns’s attack on Kim in Film Comment.
>   In the case of mumblecore, ***the blogosphere’s attitude was more
>   hype-driven***; when the IFC Center launched its mumblecore series last
>   year, every blog affiliated with indieWIRE united to promote it. The
>   only criticisms heard about the films related to their all-white
>   casts, not esthetics. I’m not sure what Korean film and mumblecore
>   have in common, although the parallels between the latter and the
>   blogosphere are obvious, but I think bloggers like making discoveries
>   they can claim as their own.

I Couldn't find the definition anywhere! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It means driven more by [*hype*](http://i.word.com/idictionary/hype) than by substance.

Comment: Dan has said it all.  Hype-driven means ... "driven by hype!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think *hype-driven* in this context  refers to the fact that when talking about mumblecore movies, the atmosphere was more excited and  talkative to contrast  with the more serious discussion about the Korean cinema.

[Hype:](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/hype)

> - Excitement, talk.

Source: www.onlineslangdictionary.com

Comment: In OP's exact context, the fact that the tone of discussions about mumblecore is "excited and talkative" is effectively taken as a "given". What the cited extract says is that the collective blogosphere's ***attitude*** to mumblecore is ***driven/shaped*** by that hype.

Answer (score 1):

*Hype-driven* is simply a joining of [hype](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hype) and [driven](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hype). Something that is driven (caused to go forward) by hype (enthusiatic promoting of something).